# Is it wrong for a Christian to prefer (within the body of Christ) a marriage partner of a race different than his own?

Tags: marriage, culture

He grew up as a missionary in a different culture than his own and speaks the language, is it sinful for him to want to marry one of that race rather than one of his own race? (no bias toward his own or any other race).

If he knew it was God's will he would marry whomever God wants, whether of that race or not. But to him he naturally likes the culture, language, etc of the race he grew up in.

Comment: While no doubt there would certainly be some Christians who think so, most are pretty convinced that racism is wrong.

Comment: Are you asking us if it permissible for a pious and devout Christian (presumably [the son of] a missionary) to marry a non-Christian ? Or whether it is forbidden for preachers and missionaries to marry their parishioners (similar to how psychologists deem it unethical to become romantically entangled with their clients) ? Or simply if Christianity considers it a sin to marry someone of another race or ethnicity, even if both of them might be Christians ?

Comment: I'm asking if it's sin for a believer to want to marry another believer of a different race rather than a believer of their own race

Comment: Moses married an Ethiopian woman and was criticised for it (by Miriam and Aaron). But scripture makes no criticism, Numbers 12:1.The Bride in the Song of Solomon says 'I am black but comely', Song of Solomon 1:5.

Comment: @Nigel J 
That makes sense and I appreciate that answer. But it just does not feel right to do so within the united body of Christ, even if it feels natural. How do you reconcile a God who shows no favoritism with this?

Comment: @MarcosRequena I have answered you from scripture but you seem to prefer your own opinion. I am sorry, I cannot further assist.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not trying to have an opinion. I just want to completely ensure that I am not in sin.

Comment: God shows no partiality, but in choosing a wife you will have to show partiality; you'll marry one woman, not all women. So you'll have to choose on the basis of some criteria, for example, is she a Christian? will she be a good mother for our children? Etc. As others have said, nothing in scripture prohibits taking race into account, but it seems (to me) irrational to give race very high importance. Perhaps you should pray for guidance about criteria and their relative importance.

Comment: I agree with you about the importance. It is low on the list, obviously far below the importance of the other criteria you mentioned. I just want to honor Christ in all my decisions, and I didn't know if even taking race into any consideration was biblical.

Comment: Why was this Question closed? It seems on-topic to me. Indeed, I’m pretty sure that there’s a definitive answer to it that quotes one particular verse that neither of the current Answers have referenced.

Comment: Which verse is that

Comment: You have to be basing this on OT passages given exclusively to Israel against ONLY the nations descending from Canaan the grandson of Noah. “You shall not intermarry with them, giving your daughters to their sons or taking their daughters for your sons,”
‭‭Deuteronomy‬ ‭7:3‬ this was then erroneously extended to all people everywhere by extremely zealot leaders of the southern kingdom to the point that they refused to even marry anyone from the northern ten tribes who were Israeli/Hebrew like themselves

Answer (score 3):

The question is based on the assumption that race exists.

Biblical terminology for race has been used to classify human races, based on proposed Biblical lineage from the Table of Nations in Genesis 10, since antiquity.

The early modern biblical division of the world's races into Semites, Hamites and Japhetites was coined at the Göttingen School of History in the late 18th century – in parallel with the color terminology for race which divided mankind into five colored races.

Identifying human races in terms of skin color, at least as one among several physiological characteristics, has been common since antiquity. Via rabbinical literature, the division is received in early modern scholarship, mostly in four to five categories. It was long recognized that the number of categories is arbitrary and subjective. François Bernier (1684) doubted the validity of using skin color as a racial characteristic, and Charles Darwin emphasized the gradual differences between categories. Modern genetics has completely nullified the concept of there being multiple human races.

Comment: So it's not right for a believer to want to marry a believer of a different culture rather than their own culture first? It seems like it would be sin, but if so how can it be repented of and forsaken when it seems so natural to the individual form growing up in that culture? Please note it has nothing to do with the terms race or skin color.

Comment: "culture" is a very fluid concept. For example, French and Dutch culture are very different. Where do you draw the line and why would it matter?

Comment: There are distinct geographic language and physical differences. As well as different customs, interests, food, and in general, compatibility.

Comment: In many cases, the "line" is a physical country or regional border. That is where the line is drawn

Comment: So, by that reasoning, someone from California should not marry someone from, say, Idaho? And there are no different customs and interests present in local communities and social groups? Factors like distance, taste, culture and religion do not guarantee higher compatibility. In fact, [studies say the opposite](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/things-couples-dont-need-to-have-in-common_n_5acbfa9ce4b07a3485e796ca).

Comment: I am not saying that they shouldn't marry. I also know that there are diverse personalities within one's own "social group". One does not necessarily have to marry another from a different country, because someone from their own country or "social group" could have the traits they consider desirable. There are African-Americans, Asian-Americans, Latinos Europeans, etc living in the US who still retain their original culture and way of life. They are all in the same "social group" whilst mantaining different cultures to an extent. Generally country is known for its dominant and distinct culture

Answer (score 1):

There is no scripture that condemns interracial marriage. We MUST go by scripture and not 'what seems', or 'what person xxx believes'. If the Word is silent on a particular subject, then we have to ask Him to reveal to us.

Since you cannot find any scriptures described, the answer should be obvious-- it is not sin regardless of what anyone thinks unless they can quote you book, chapter and verse of a scripture that states otherwise.

Comment: Aren't we told, however that "God shows no partiality"? So then, is it a sin to prefer physical and cultural characteristics in a potential spouse (seeing that the spouse is Christian, of course). Is this attitude racist or sinful?

Comment: Indeed: God is no respecter of persons. Can you find any scripture which speaks of preference of any physical/cultural aspect as being a sin? "For there is neither Jew nor Greek..."

Comment: No, not necessarily. There is no Jew or Greek sure, but we don't want to justify the world's accusation of being racist either. I'm not saying it is racist, but some evangelicals would say so. I'm trying to look at it biblicaly and repent if it's sin. Basically, Christ did not save us based on our culture or physique, That is true love. Should not we want to love like Christ?

Comment: Sorry I am not following you. Can you find any scripture which speaks of preference of any physical/cultural aspect as being a sin? Yes or No.

Comment: No I can't. At least not directly.

Comment: But do you think that it is racist?

Comment: It matters not what I think. Since you cannot find any scriptures described, the answer should be obvious-- it is not sin regardless of what anyone thinks unless they can quote you book, chapter and verse of a scripture that states otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the wisdom and your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @peinal could you edit your answer again to fold in more completely some of the points that you shared in the comments?  Answers being too terse can detract from their qualty, and comments are temporary.  You may need to caveat your reply somewhat, as you seem to be coming to this from a "sola scriptura" perspective - which is not universal among Christians.

Comment: @korvinStarmast:  not sure I understand exactly what you are asking. You like what I said, but didn't like how I said it? or? I am not a biblical 'scholar' and have only heard the term 'sola scriptura'--not fully sure what it means.  I think it means I have a strong belief in 'only what the Word states'--which would be quite accurate for my understanding of how one should view the Word.

Comment: The edit helped, yes, but my other point is that only *some* denominations of Christianity are "it's only so if you can find it in scripture down to chapter and verse ... " -  opinion isn't what SE sites are all about.  *which would be quite accurate for my understanding of how one should view the Word*  <-- That's heaing into opinion. 
 Please take the [tour], see the [help], as well as [ask] and [answer]. This isn't a forum.  (Though referring to scripture to support an answer is highly encouraged in a general sense ... )

Comment: @korvinStarmast: if it is not book, chapter and verse, then, what is it, if it is not opinion? I am confused exactly why BCV is 'opinion'. Sorry.

Comment: @peinal Your opinion on how scripture is to be treated is the point I am making. [Suggest you read through this](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/24204). My intent is to help  you understand this sites format.

Comment: OK then. If this is not a Christian site, I don't belong here.

Comment: @peinal I think there should be a separate Stack Exchange site for Catholicism. Most if not all true Christians I know adhere to sola scriptura and Reformation doctrine. I think it causes unnecessary friction to have Protestant/Catholics on the same site answering the same questions

Comment: I am not Catholic.

Comment: @user50470 Amen!